# Single variable functions optimization

Tags: functions, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

The cost of producing appliances is $\$(300 + 2.2n^2)$ where $n$ is the number produced per week.
If they are sold for $\$110$ each, how many should be produced for maximum profit?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Suppose you produce and sell $n$ of them, then your revenue is $110n$ and your cost is $300+2.2n^2$, so your profit (which is revenue minus cost) is
$$110n-\left(300+2.2n^2\right).$$

Do you know how to maximise this expression over $n\ge 0$?

Comment: By taking the derivatives?

Comment: Sure, you can give that a try. (And remember that you probably ultimately care about integer $n$ only.)